# How to print warnings and errors when using setuptools (pip)

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, error-logging

I am using setuptools to package code such that it can be easily installed using

```
cd project_name && pip install .
```

During the setup process, I want to warn the user about pre-existing config files and print some post install instructions on the system. For example

```
/etc/project_name/project.conf exists. Not copying default config file.
```

I have tried to use `print` and `logging.warning()` but still the warnings don't appear when installing using pip. I have a feeling I am missing something obvious.

We are trying to support 3.0 > python >= 2.6 on Redhat family >= el6 and Ubuntu >= 14.04LTS

Comment: provide your `setup.py`with `logging`/`print`

Comment: @AzatIbrakov I have tried that, using `logging.warning()` and `print()` it does not show up.

Comment: add your `setup.py` script so we can see what you've tried so far

Answer (score 8):

If you take a look at the pip source, in the function responsible for running the setup script, `call_subprocess` ([source here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/main/src/pip/_internal/utils/subprocess.py#L71)), it says:

```
def call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, cwd=None, ...
    """
    Args:
      show_stdout: if true, use INFO to log the subprocess's stderr and
        stdout streams.  Otherwise, use DEBUG.  Defaults to False.
      ...
    """
    ...
    # Most places in pip use show_stdout=False. What this means is--
    #
    # - We connect the child's output (combined stderr and stdout) to a
    #   single pipe, which we read.
    # - We log this output to stderr at DEBUG level as it is received.
    # - If DEBUG logging isn't enabled (e.g. if --verbose logging wasn't
    #   requested), then we show a spinner so the user can still see the
    #   subprocess is in progress.
    # - If the subprocess exits with an error, we log the output to stderr
    #   at ERROR level if it hasn't already been displayed to the console
    #   (e.g. if --verbose logging wasn't enabled).  This way we don't log
    #   the output to the console twice.
    #
    # If show_stdout=True, then the above is still done, but with DEBUG
    # replaced by INFO.
```

In short, you can see the output only if:

- your setup exits with an error, or
- user calls pip with `-v`, the verbose flag

Comment: Updated the link for the latest versions of pip.

Comment: Thanks @JongwookChoi, I've updated the code/comments accordingly.